# What is the afterlife for non-warrior Klingons?

Tags: star-trek, klingon

The basic plot is known: at first sight, the Klingons are an aggressive, but honor centered warrior culture. There is a "heaven" (**Sto-vo-kor** / **Sto'Vo'Kor** etc.) for the warriors who died in combat with honor. And there is a "hell" (**Gre'Thor** / **ghe'tor** etc.) for the dishonored ones.

However, there are a lot of Klingons who are not warriors. Actually, most of the population cannot be a full time warrior (soldier). One can also live in honor as a non-warrior, but what is the afterlife concept e.g., for a Klingon agriculturalist, who dies by old age instead of in a fight with an especially aggressive mutant carrot?

Comment: Presumably the Klingons have some form of National Service, which means that they all served in the military at some point in their lives. That might be sufficient (in terms of 'honour gained') to last a lifetime.

Comment: Yes, that is probably true, but most of them survive the "compulsory years of service" and die as an old farmer and not in battle.

Comment: There's always the possibility of performing a heroic deed yourself to ensure others enter Sto Vo Kor. That's what Worf did for Jadzia.

Comment: That would be too much offering. I don't know the exact numbers for the Klingon society, but let see eg. Israel, which has the third most active soldier per capita ([according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_number_of_military_and_paramilitary_personnel) ). That is 20 active military person per 1000. With this ratio, every Klingon soldier has to make 50 "honor kills" for the rest of the others.

Comment: It does not need to be a kill; just a heroic deed. Also, it's more complex than just killing. B'Elannas mother died dishonered because of what B'Elanna did, the circumstances of her death did not seem to matter. Her otherwise honorable life seems to have been enough for a ticket to Sto Vo Kor if it hadn't been for her daughter.

Comment: @Philipp - Note that it was left ambiguous in that episode as to whether what B'Elanna experienced (regarding the Barge of the Dead and her mother) was real or not.

Comment: Real or not, the myths the experience built upon were never commented by her as inconsistent with what she knows about Sto'Vo'Kor.

Comment: @Philipp - Yes, B'Elanna's visions reflected her beliefs regarding Klingon culture, regardless of whether they also reflected reality or not. That said, she isn't the greatest authority on Klingon culture, and it wasn't clear that, if not for B'Elanna's dishonour, her mother would necessarily have been granted a ticket to Sto-vo-kor based purely on having lived an honourable life. That's a logical leap, and one that doesn't align well with Worf's belief that Jadzia would be barred from Sto-vo-kor on account of not having died in battle. Jadzia otherwise lived an honourable life as well.

Comment: @LogicDictates while you do have a point, I also think it's a leap to assume that the myth presented to us in this episode is crucially different from the real thing, without giving us any indication that there is a difference. As to Worf, all the information we have about his motivation is second-hand from an ironic discussion of Bashir, Quark and O'Brien.  The whole idea that Jadzia gets a place in Sto Vo Kor since she joined the House of Martok seems exclusively Worf's idea and I have always thought this was his way of grieving about her death and not grounded firmly in reality.

Comment: I would simply assume a system similar to the Vikings-Norse culture. Dying in battle with blade in hand meant the VIP section of Valhalla. Farmers and normal folk  suffered the "straw death" and wandered the frozen plains of Hel.

Comment: The great vegetable rebellion has generated many songs and carrot stories of the great deeds done in that battle. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W8gKEp-JlPI

Comment: @Philipp - I'm not assuming there is a difference between the way the Klingon afterlife was presented in B'Elanna's visions and reality. But we don't whether her mother actually died or not, or the circumstances of her death, if she did. We don't know much about her mother's life in general. And where there's any apparent conflict in their beliefs, I'll defer to Worf's views on Klingon culture over B'Elanna's any day. He embraced that culture, whereas she largely rejected it.

Comment: @LogicDictates we do know Miral is dead, it’s referenced later in voyager. But granted, we don’t know much more. However, we also don’t know much about how word personally looks at Klingon faith, the crucial bits of information are discussed onscreen only in his absence and in a comical/ironic context.

Comment: @Philipp - We know that Worf undertook a dangerous mission on a Klingon Bird-of-Prey with the express purpose of getting Jadzia into Sto-vo-kor. https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Shadows_and_Symbols_(episode)

Comment: @LogicDictates yes and we know nothing about how much of this was a religious necessity for any Klingon, how much of this was necessary because jadzia was not originally Klingon and how much of this was worf‘s way of grieving. On screen most, if not  all of this is explained in passing by bashir, quark and O’Brien. Jadzia being eligible for entering sto vo kor is especially strange and handwaved away with „worf seems to think so“. Not a strong assertion if you ask me.

Comment: @Philipp - Not sure why you keep reiterating that some of the information was relayed by characters other than Worf. It was clearly his belief, based on his own words and actions, that the mission needed to carried out in order to get Jadzia into Sto-vo-kor. The only thing that was questioned was whether or not Jadzia actually counted as a Klingon or not. But even if she didn't, for the sake of argument, the implication of Worf's words and actions is that the manner of a Klingon's death was pivotal in in determining whether they'd automatically be granted entry to Sto-vo-kor in the afterlife.

Comment: Because it‘s not as clear as you present it. Worf has a different view on the Klingon belief system than most other Klingons, possibly due to his unique background. I would treat his view on this with the same caution as B‘Elanna‘s (for different reasons though). Therefore it’s highly relevant to understand the context of worf‘s thought process, which we unfortunately don’t see first hand. For example, its not enough for him to ensure jadzia‘s entrance to sto vo kor, he wants to do it alone, which is not necessary as per the myth and called out on screen.

Answer (score 4):

Klingon farmers, teachers and lawyers used to go to heaven, but now they probably go to hell. Fashions in Klingon society seem to have shifted away from being able to gain honour from merely living your life well ("*through integrity and acts of true courage*") to a society that praises only acts of martial valour.

> **KOLOS:** *Oh, I'm not sure. Over two hundred. But that was a long time ago, when the tribunal was a forum for the truth and not a tool for the warrior class.*
>
> **ARCHER:** *There are other classes?*
>
> **KOLOS:** *You didn't believe all Klingons were soldiers?*
>
> **ARCHER:** *I guess I did.*
>
> **KOLOS:** *My father was a teacher. My mother, a biologist at the university. They encouraged me to take up the law. Now all young people want to do is take up weapons as soon as they can hold them. They're told there's honour in victory, any victory. What honour is there in a victory over a weaker opponent? Had Duras destroyed that ship he would have been lauded as a hero of the Empire for murdering helpless refugees. **We were a great society not so long ago, when honour was earned through integrity and acts of true courage, not senseless bloodshed.***
>
> <sub><sup>ENT: Justice</sup></sub>

Note that this isn't far from Earth societies like the Vikings, where honoured warriors might end up in Valhalla, but farmers could just as easily end up in Fólkvangr or one of the other (equally nice) afterlives, just not the one devoted to being a warrior.

Comment: kind of like dog heaven, cat heaven and fish heaven

Comment: @sfhq_sf - The vikings had a bunch of heavens. Valhalla was just the most famous